# How to make a Mac app made in 10.6 work in 10.5

Tags: xcode, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, compatibility, osx-leopard

I recently made an app on a Mac running OS X 10.6. I now want that app to work on 10.5.x systems. I changed the target build in xcode from 10.6 to 10.5 in the project settings which led to some code changes. But when I try it on 10.5 it just shows a "stop-sign" on the app-icon:

[image]

These are my Xcode build settings:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Can you run it on the Snow Leopard system and see any logged information on the Console?

Comment: What happens when you double-click on the application anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you cross-compile your app 32-bit (and ppc if you are supporting PPC 10.5 machines)?

Comment: smorgan: No, I don't think so. How do I do this?

Comment: These are my settings: http://imageshack.us/f/685/settingsps.png/ - This should cover 10.5 and newer right?

Comment: You don't show the deployment target; that should also be 10.5. And if you want it to run on PPC machines (you don't say if the 10.5 machine you tested was PPC or Intel), you need to include that in Architectures.